# triggering a list of functions based on finding matching strings within a cells data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Below is a function I have put together, that I would like to use to trigger 4 different email functions based on the content of a cell within my google sheet. However it doesn't seem to work. Just wondering if anyone can help me out and show me where I am going wrong?

```
function emailAlerts() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var activerow = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var startRow = activerow;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 1;   // Number of rows to process
    // Fetch the range of cells
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 44)
    // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];    
  var checkdata = sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 43).getValue(); // Email Alerts column
  if (checkdata.indexOf("Engineering") > -1) {
  sendEngineeringEmails();
  } 
  if (checkdata.indexOf("Cleaners") > -1) {
  sendCleanersEmails();
  }
  if (checkdata.indexOf("Advertising") > -1) {
  sendAdvertisingEmails();
  }
  if (checkdata.indexOf("Management") > -1) {
  sendManagementEmails();
  } 
 }
}
```

The Cell that contains the data might be formatted like this on one row

```
Engineering, Cleaners, Advertising, Management
```

and like this on another row

```
Cleaners, Advertising
```

or like this on yet another row

```
Engineering, Management
```

I need to search the data to find a match of the required strings to be able to trigger the relevant email functions. The email functions all work fine on their own but I'm having a problem automating things with this new function so that the right emails are sent. I need it to be able to send to one Email function or in some cases all 4 email functions based on what is submitted to the data containing cell on each row (this data comes from a Google Form and is based on a checklist type of form question where the form user can select the options from a list)

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: Hi Parag, I'm not seeing any errors it just doesn't trigger the functions.

Comment: Check my answer, see if it solves your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have data in the form like below

[image: Google Spreadsheet Data Format]

Then your code should be like this. Check code for comments

```
function emailAlerts()
{
  //INSTEAD OF THIS TRY THE CODE BELOW USING "openById" & "getSheetByName" METHODS.
  //  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  //  var activerow = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();

  //IS THERE A PARTICULAR REASON FOR USING TWO DIFFERENT VARIABLES WITH SAME VALUES
  //  var startRow = activerow;  // First row of data to process
  //  var numRows = 1;   // Number of rows to process

  //COULD BE DONE IN ONE LINE
  //  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 44)
  //  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1BZuYFCnN_g9vn5crxbPeYlhUKwH6N3u0uT8LCmm-neM").getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();   // Number of rows to process
  var data = sheet.getRange(1, 1, numRows, 1).getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i)
  {
    var row = data[i].toString();

    //NEVER CALL APIS IN FOR LOOP, IT CAN HAVE DRASTIC EFFECT ON PERFORMANCE
    //var checkdata = sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 43).getValue();
    Logger.log("Index: "+i)

    if (row.indexOf("Engineering") > -1)
    {
      Logger.log("sendEngineeringEmails()");
    } 
    if (row.indexOf("Cleaners") > -1)
    {
      Logger.log("sendCleanersEmails()");
    }
    if (row.indexOf("Advertising") > -1)
    {
      Logger.log("sendAdvertisingEmails()");
    }
    if (row.indexOf("Management") > -1)
    {
      Logger.log("sendManagementEmails()");
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Heaps Parag :) I'll have a crack at running your code tonight and see if I can get it working. Thanks for taking the time my friend